# Django Djoser: Email address reset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, email-address, djoser

I am using username for primary identification. However, users also have email addresses. I would like to know how can I set up "email address reset" so that users can change their email addresses. This functionality seems obvious to me but I did not find anything - am I missing something or maybe my approach is not correct?

Oh, and I would like to keep the username as is, I just want to make it possible to change the email with confirmations etc. I think it is important to have an email sent to the new address first and only then change it.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have smtp server configured already?

Comment: Hey Al Amin. I have successfully configured password reset and account activation. The problem is I am not aware if this email reset thing is even supported by Djoser. Of course I could reverse engineer it but from what I see it is not. And logic tells me that if it really is nothing you can do to reset your email, then this is a huge flaw. This is why I think there should be something. If there is not, I guess I will have to implement it by myself. Which I also consider (and maybe create a pull request, IDK)

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest you watch this awesome Djoser tutorial [Django Rest Framework Authentication Crash Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddB83a4jKSY) then you need to set up your email configuration with your gmail API or sendgrid API. Here is a sample code you need to put in your settings

For gmail

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your email address@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'gmail API Key (password)'
```

copy templates from [REST implementation of Django authentication system](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/tree/8f65bfff16577c7fb0f52bbabf5fb69f6809ba62) 
then in the settings add your html like below

```
'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password_changed_confirmation/password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'username_changed_confirmation/username/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activation/activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {},
```

Hope this will help